# RailsAdmin: undefined method `link_to' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::String>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using RailsAdmin and I'm trying to put in admin panel a link to a video stored on AWS.

```
field :license do
    formatted_value do
      link_to 'license', value
    end
  end
  field :insurance do
    formatted_value do
      link_to 'insurance', value
    end
  end
  field :registration do
    formatted_value do
      link_to 'registration', value
    end
  end
  field :interview do
    pretty_value do
      link_to 'Download video', value.url
    end
  end
```

This is my rails_admin.rb (config file) for the part I'm trying to configure. The first 3 fields work, but on INTERVIEW field I get

```
undefined method `link_to' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::String:0xc83a7f0>
```

Do you have any suggestions what to do in order to get a link in that field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I just had to do the same thing. I'm assuming you fixed your issue given the age of this question but I may as well jump in here for anybody else trying to work it out.

You can access `link_to` like so:

```
field :interview do
  pretty_value do
    bindings[:view].link_to('Download video', value.url)
  end
end
```